# How to call a non-const method from a const method?

Tags: c++, methods, constants, const-correctness

I've got a const method in my class, which cannot be changed to non-const. In this method, I need to call a non-const method but the compiler doesn't let me do that.

Is there any way around it? Here is a simplified sample of my code:

```
int SomeClass::someMethod() const {
    QColor saveColor = color();
    setColor(QColor(255,255,255)); // Calling non-const method

    // ....

    setColor(saveColor); // restore color

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be against the cardinal rule of being a const function ?

Comment: @DumbCoder, from the outside, it is a const function in that nothing visible to the client has been changed.

Comment: A non-const method implies that it is changing some data in your object. If `someMethod()` calls a non-const method, then it is indirectly changing data. So really, `someMethod()` simply shouldn't be `const`.

Comment: The `mutable` keyword allows changing data in a const method, yet nobody would suggest to stop using mutable and change the method to non-const. As a programmer, I know that I'm setting a color, then restoring this color. I know the data hasn't been changed, so I'm looking for a way to indicate that to the compiler.

Comment: @Laurent: what you say is true, but if someone creates a `const` instance of `SomeClass`, then it is defined behavior to modify its `mutable` members, but UB to modify its non-mutable members. Therefore, there is an important difference between the situation you actually have and the situation you compare it to. The effect of marking `someMethod` const is to allow callers to call it on const objects, as well as calling it on non-const objects via references-to-const, and you can't separate the two. Casting away const relies on the caller only using the function on non-const objects.

Comment: A potential solution is to alter the code in `// ....` so that it doesn't need to use the object's "current color". Add versions of all the functions you use, that take a `QColor` parameter instead. That relies on being able to change the interfaces used in the hidden code, of course. It may also have different behavior - in your code, if `// ....` throws then the object's color has been changed, whereas you'll lose that effect in my suggestion.

Comment: Another possibility: is the object `SomeClass` copyable? You could do `SomeClass sc = *this; sc.setColor(White);` then use `sc` in place of `*this` throughout `// ....`.

Comment: +1: It's a well-formed question.  Some people are probably downvoting you because they think you're trying to do the *Wrong Thing*, but IMO that's not the right reason to downvote.  In any case, I'm not upvoting to offset the downvotes -- I'm upvoting because it's a well-formed question.

Comment: @Laurent "_from the outside, it is a const function in that nothing visible to the client has been changed_" from the outside, this function cannot be called on a `const` object

Comment: @curiousguy, yes that was my problem, I had a const object trying to call this function, which is why my code wasn't compiling.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the challenges of doing `const`-correctness is you can't do it halfway.  It's either all or nothing.  If you try to do it halfway, you end up in a tough spot like you are here.  You end up with a nice `const`-correct class being used by some crazy old, typically legacy (or written by an old curmudgeon) code that isn't `const`-correct and it just doesn't work.  You're left wondering if `const`-correctness is worth all the trouble.

```
I need to call a non-const method [from a const method]
```

You can't -- not directly.  Nor should you.  However, there is an alternative...

Obviously you can't call a non-`const` method from a `const` method.  Otherwise, `const` would have no meaning when applied to member functions.

A `const` member function can change member variables marked `mutable`, but you've indicated that this is not possible in your case.

You could attempt to cast away `const`ness by doing something like `SomeClass* me = const_cast<SomeClass*>(this);` but A) This will typically result in UB, or 2) It violates the whole idea of `const`-correctness.

One thing you could do, if what you're really trying to accomplish would support this, is to create a non-`const` proxy object, and do non`const`-y stuff with that.  To wit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Gizmo
{
public:
    Gizmo() : n_(42) {};
    void Foo() const;
    void Bar() { cout << "Bar() : " << n_ << "\n"; }
    void SetN(int n) { n_ = n; };
    int GetN() const { return n_; }
private:
    int n_;
};

void Gizmo::Foo() const
{
    // we want to do non-const'y things, so create a proxy...
    Gizmo proxy(*this);
    int save_n = proxy.GetN();
    proxy.SetN(save_n + 1);
    proxy.Bar();
    proxy.SetN(save_n);
}

int main()
{
    Gizmo gizmo;
    gizmo.Foo();
}
```

Comment: How is it useful? I'm confused. The proxy here is not a proxy, for it doesn't represent the original object. It is just a local object with no extraordinary power. Working with proxy is not equivalent to working with the original object.

Comment: @nawaz: if it helps op get his work done in a standard-conformant way, its useful.

Comment: Sometimes a class is written without const markers because C++ devs are lazy, so being able to say "this *really* is const even though it's not marked as such" is a thing sometimes.

Answer (score 23):

You could use `const_cast` on `this` pointer,

```
int SomeClass::someMethod() const {
    const_cast<SomeClass*>( this )->setColor(...);// Calling non-const method
    //whatever
}
```

but if you do that for an object that was originally declared `const` you run into undefined behavior.

So this:

```
SomeClass object;
object.someMethod();
```

is okay, but this:

```
const SomeClass object;
object.someMethod();
```

yields undefined behavior.

The real solution is that your `const` function should not be `const` in the first place.

Comment: I suppose one could use a factory and private constructors, to ensure that there are no `const` instances of `SomeClass`. But unless that's already there, it's a much bigger change to the class interface than the changes that the questioner is forbidden to make, so probably not much help.

Comment: This is a better answer than the marked one as it explains when you can get undefined behaviour. Sometimes you have no choice but to cast away const.

Answer (score 10):

If you require to change some internal state inside a `const`-method you can also declare the affected state `mutable`:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void doStuff() const { bar = 5; }
private:
    mutable int bar;
};
```

This is intended for cases where you have stuff like mutexes as members of your class. Acquiring and releasing a mutex does not affect client-visible state, but is technically forbidden in a `const`-method. The solution is to mark the mutex `mutable`. Your case looks similar, although I think your class requires some refactoring for this solution to be applicable.

Also, you might want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553109/160206) to see how you can make this temporary state-change exception-safe using RAII.

Answer (score 6):

> How to call a non-const method from a const method?

You should not. You might run into undefined behaviour if you cast away the const-ness of `this`, using `const_cast`. The usage of`const_cast` will shut the compiler's mouth up, but that isn't a solution. If you need to do, then it means the const function should not be `const` in the first place. Make it non-const.

Or,  you should do something else, which would not require you to call non-const function from `const` function. Like, don't call `setColor` function? Like, split the const function into more than one functions (if you can do that)?  Or something else?

In your particular case, if `setColor` only sets some member variable, say `m_color`, then you can declare it `mutable`:

```
 mutable QColor m_color;
```

and then set it in your const function, without calling `setColor` function, and without doing `const_cast`.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question as I just wrote I cannot change it to non-const.

Comment: @Laurent, potentially you could, if you could make the members touched in that function `mutable`?

Comment: If this is not an answer to your question, then your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @tenfour, then vote to close it. If there's no answer, there's no point answering off-topic.

Comment: @Laurent: if it gets closed, how would know what is wrong with the question? Does closing *please* you more than *attempting* to your answer?

Comment: @Nawaz, my comment was applying to your very first post. Your current answer is very useful in explaining the problem and what to do about it.