# Calling JNI functions from a const method

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I want to call the Java bindings of my C++ class like that :

```
std::streamsize DataStreamJava::length() const {
  jmethodID m = jni()->GetMethodID(j_dataStream_class_,
                                   "length", "()J");
  return jni()->CallLongMethod(j_dataStream_global_, m);
}
```

But it is not possible since these JNI calls are not const.

Does JNI provide const functions for const methods ? Is removing const attributes the only way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you have a `const JNIEnv*` for some reason?  Why?

Comment: To expand on @TavianBarnes' comment: you can keep a pointer to `JNIEnv` in your object, but you have no control on the `JNIEnv`, it does not belong to your object or class. Therefore it is perfectly legitimate to declare it as **mutable**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the short answer is "no."  There's no `const` version of these JNI functions.  The next question maybe is "Should there be?"  I think that the answer to that is also "no."  JNI functions all potentially change the state of the JVM. (At minimum they all have the capability to create an error in the JVM, which changes its internal state.)  I think that *actually* violates the contract implied by your `const` attribute - It's not just some design flaw in the JNI header files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've finally decided to remove the const attributes from the methods used with JNI.

Answer (score 1):

JNI apart, **you want to invoke a *non-const* method inside a *const* one**.

I think you can do it using a [**`const_cast<>`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008541/how-to-call-a-non-const-function-within-a-const-function-c), but read the [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325400/how-to-call-a-non-const-method-from-a-const-method) first.

Answer (score 1):

If JNI doesn't have the const annotations you want, this may be a case where **`mutable`** might actually be a good idea.  Tag the JNI members as `mutable` and check logical const-ness by hand.