# Non const inside const

Tags: c++, constants

```
class A
{
void koo(){}
void foo() const {this->koo();}
};

int main()
{
A a;
a.foo();
}
```

I tried to call a non-const function inside const function.

```
error: passing ‘const A’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void A::koo()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

1. What is the meaning of this error?
2. Can I use mutable keyword for this, If that, how? ([as this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008541/how-to-call-a-non-const-function-within-a-const-function-c))
3. Can I use const_cast for this. If that, how? ([as this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008541/how-to-call-a-non-const-function-within-a-const-function-c))
4. Are there ant other way to do this?

Comment: it means you are trying to call a non-const function from within a `const`. Nope. Yes - but hacky (`const_cast<A*>(this)->koo()`). Yes, make `koo()` `const` and any state it operates on `mutable`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do inside of `koo()`?

Comment: This is exactly the reason for the const qualifier, it prevents you executing non-const code on a const object. You may need to rethink your design, if you're having this problem, or maybe the function that your calling the non-const member function from really should be const.

Comment: @Nim `const_cast` will lead to undefined behaviour if `koo` really mutates the object.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes It won't, because it's called on a non-const object. And if called on a const object, it's undefined regardless of whether it mutates the object, is it not?

Comment: @hvd: I'm pretty sure it's OK to call a non-const function on a const object provided it doesn't mutate. But it's one of those cases where I claim there is no text in the standard saying X, which given the size of the standard is difficult to conclusively prove.

Comment: @SteveJessop I was under the impression that it was the same as calling a non-virtual method on a null pointer, or on an object of a different type, if it doesn't access any members: it won't fail in practise, but it's still invalid. I'll see if I can find a quote.

Comment: @hvd: there's nothing wrong in principle with creating a pointer-to-non-const that points to a const object. It's only writing through it that causes UB. The same is not true of `volatile`, btw: reading *or* writing through a pointer-to-non-volatile that points at a volatile object is UB.

Comment: If you change `koo();` to be `koo() const;`, make sure it isn't an override for a virtual function, as you'll be declaring a new function overload rather than overriding the virtual base.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, wasn't sure of the UB, but sure is hacky, which in my book is a Bad Thing(tm)...

Comment: @SteveJessop I think you're right. There's a special exception that makes it invalid to call nonstatic member functions for invalid values of `this` that would be valid if `this` were an explicit pointer argument of a static/non-member function ([class.mfct.non-static]p2). That exception doesn't say anything about `const`/`volatile`, and the text that follows that describes the `const`/`volatile` modifies doesn't say any such thing either.

Comment: @hvd "And if called on a const object, it's undefined regardless of whether it mutates the object, is it not?" is exactly the crux of the matter: if you're going to make it impossible to call on a const object, C++ has a way to do that: remove the const qualifier (don't make UB easy!). Client code can then `const_cast` itself if it knows the object is not really const. If you want to make it possible to work on a const object, C++ also has a way to do that: make the fields `mutable`. Basically, I think using `const_cast` to cause mutation on a `const` function is the wrongest of all options.

Answer (score 4):

1. In function `foo`, `this` has type `const A*`. In order to call a non-const function on it, you'd end up with `this` in `koo` having the same value but type `A*`, i.e. it would discard const qualifiers.
2. No.
3. You could, because you happen to know that the `koo` function doesn't modify any const objects that are data members of `A` (because (a) the function body is empty and (b) `A` has no data members and (c) it's called on a non-const instance of `A` anyway). But don't do that.
4. Mark `koo` as a `const` member function, same as `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

`koo` isn't declared as `const`, this indicates that it *could* change the object somehow, which isn't allowed on const objects. The signature of `foo` indicates that the current object (`this`) should be considered to be constant.

You'll need to specify a `const` variant of `koo`:

```
void koo() const {}
void koo() {}
```

Comment: And if the original `koo` doesn't change the object's state, it's not even necessary to overload: just add `const` to the original method.

Comment: @hvd Unless koo is a virtual function in which case changing to const will mean the base version isn't overridden any-more.

Comment: @PeterWood Good point. In that case, add `const` to the original method, and make the non-const override call the const version. Technically that's an overload, but you don't end up with two separate implementations.

Answer (score 0):

if `koo` is declared not const (ie it modifies the internal state of the object) then indeed `foo` is not const.

Either make `koo`const, `foo` not const, or if the object act like "with no state" but has internal variables that must be updated, then make these variables `mutable`.

```
mutable int m_accessCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function as `const`, you are saying "this function does *never* change the object". This allows you to use the function on `const` objects.

In your case, you are calling a non-const function from inside of a const one, which means that you cannot ensure the object will not change. This leads to an error, since the `const` on `foo()` implies the object must not change in any case.

Please avoid using `const_cast`, since it can cause UB if used improperly.

The best way to fix it is to provide a `const` version of `koo()`. Either write a non-modifying version of it, or (if it doesn't modify the object as it is) just add the `const` keyword.