# C++ static method needed

Tags: c++, static, constants, static-methods

I have a method `run()` member of `MyClass`. At compilation, i get

```
    Error   3   error C2662: 'MyClass::run' : 
    cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const MyClass' to 'MyClass&'
```

ITOH, if I put make this method static, i have no error. Method call occurs here:

```
Errors MyClass::execute( const AbstractExecutionContext &ctx ) const
{
    Errors errs;

    Watch wat; wat.restart();
    {

        run() ;

    }

    return errs;
}
```

and declaration for this method is

```
Errors execute(const AbstractExecutionContext &ctx) const;
```

I wish i can make this method not static, because if it is static, methods called by run() must be static as well, and data members that are non static cannot be accessed (i have to uglyly pass them as arguments to methods).

What is the reason for compilation error, and what would be a solution ?

Comment: Is it possible to add the full code? Or at least the class definitions?

Comment: this link may help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008541/how-to-call-a-non-const-function-within-a-const-function-c

Comment: it looks like you are using `this.something` instead of `this->something`. But the error seems to be in `MyClass::run()` and not in `MyClass::execute()`

Comment: Where is the static method?

Comment: run() is not static --> i get error. run() is static --> no error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`run` must be `const` too. or function `execute` should not be `const`.

In your execute function `this` is `const MyClass* const this`. When `run` is not `static` and not `const` - there is attempt to call `non-const` function of `const` object. If `run` is static - all works fine, since `static` functions has no `this` pointer.

Comment: Static methods don't have a this pointer, there's no object state to keep constant.

Comment: lets say my solution is to make all methods called by run() static, and that i make all data member i need static as well. then is it possible to change value for this data members at run time ?

Comment: @antitrust yes, but static members's owner is CLASS, not OBJECT.

Comment: is it possible then to change value for static member at any time with  MyClass::member = val ;  ?

Comment: is it more appropriate to have data member that i pass as arguments of all static methods